# Get missing months from date for each and every id

Tags: greenplum

I have a table which contains, memberid and date. I want to display for each and every member get the missing months from date.

Here is the input table and expected table.

[image]

I have tried creating a temp table to generate series  from min month to max month, but I am failing to join the two tables.
Can anyone help me in doing this.

Here is the code I have tried so, far.

Extracting dates and storing it in new column

```
create temp table temp_table as select *, date_part('month', premiumpadidate) from training.premium  distributed by(memberid);
```

Generate series

```
create temp table temp_table_series as 
(select * from generate_series(cast((select min(date_part) from temp_table group by (memberid)) as integer), cast((select max(date_part) from temp_table group by (memberid)) as integer) )
) 
distributed by (generate_series)
```

I am not understanding how to join the two tables to get the missing months of each and every employee.

Please help me in doing this

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done with a function, but you could acomplish in a single select. Here is what I did to help you. I simulated your data with a union, and added a "102" member:

```
select 101 as id, '2016-01-01'::date as paidDate union
select 101 as id, '2016-02-01'::date as paidDate union
select 101 as id, '2016-04-01'::date as paidDate union
select 101 as id, '2016-08-01'::date as paidDate union
select 101 as id, '2016-11-01'::date as paidDate union
select 102 as id, '2016-01-01'::date as paidDate union
select 102 as id, '2016-02-01'::date as paidDate union
select 102 as id, '2016-04-01'::date as paidDate union
select 102 as id, '2016-08-01'::date as paidDate union
select 102 as id, '2016-11-01'::date as paidDate
```

You should look a it as your table.

Then, with your table I did 12 "cases", in order to check the month. I put a "0" value if the month is found, and the month value if not, like this:

```
select t.id, extract(month from t.paidDate),
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 1 then 0 else 1 end as m1,
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 2 then 0 else 2 end as m2,
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 3 then 0 else 3 end as m3,
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 4 then 0 else 4 end as m4,
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 5 then 0 else 5 end as m5,
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 6 then 0 else 6 end as m6,
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 7 then 0 else 7 end as m7,
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 8 then 0 else 8 end as m8,
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 9 then 0 else 9 end as m9,
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 10 then 0 else 10 end as m10,
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 11 then 0 else 11 end as m11,
    case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 12 then 0 else 12 end as m12
from (
    select 101 as id, '2016-01-01'::date as paidDate union
    select 101 as id, '2016-02-01'::date as paidDate union
    select 101 as id, '2016-04-01'::date as paidDate union
    select 101 as id, '2016-08-01'::date as paidDate union
    select 101 as id, '2016-11-01'::date as paidDate union
    select 102 as id, '2016-01-01'::date as paidDate union
    select 102 as id, '2016-02-01'::date as paidDate union
    select 102 as id, '2016-04-01'::date as paidDate union
    select 102 as id, '2016-08-01'::date as paidDate union
    select 102 as id, '2016-11-01'::date as paidDate
) t
```

After that, we need to discard the months that exists in the data. I did that using a group by id, gettin the MIN month. This will discard the months that exists (because we zeroed them in the case), and will maintain the months that not exist. Like this:

```
select id, 
    min(m1) as m1, min(m2) as m2, min(m3) as m3, min(m4) as m4, min(m5) as m5, min(m6) as m6, 
    min(m7) as m7, min(m8) as m8, min(m9) as m9, min(m10) as m10, min(m11) as m11, min(m12) as m12
from 
(
    select t.id, extract(month from t.paidDate),
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 1 then 0 else 1 end as m1,
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 2 then 0 else 2 end as m2,
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 3 then 0 else 3 end as m3,
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 4 then 0 else 4 end as m4,
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 5 then 0 else 5 end as m5,
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 6 then 0 else 6 end as m6,
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 7 then 0 else 7 end as m7,
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 8 then 0 else 8 end as m8,
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 9 then 0 else 9 end as m9,
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 10 then 0 else 10 end as m10,
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 11 then 0 else 11 end as m11,
        case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 12 then 0 else 12 end as m12
    from 
    (
        select 101 as id, '2016-01-01'::date as paidDate union
        select 101 as id, '2016-02-01'::date as paidDate union
        select 101 as id, '2016-04-01'::date as paidDate union
        select 101 as id, '2016-08-01'::date as paidDate union
        select 101 as id, '2016-11-01'::date as paidDate union
        select 102 as id, '2016-01-01'::date as paidDate union
        select 102 as id, '2016-02-01'::date as paidDate union
        select 102 as id, '2016-04-01'::date as paidDate union
        select 102 as id, '2016-08-01'::date as paidDate union
        select 102 as id, '2016-11-01'::date as paidDate
    ) t
) t
group by t.id
```

You could you it already as your result to execute whatever rules you have, but lets clean it a little bit more, by removing the zeros, like this:

```
select id,
    case when m1 = 0 then null else m1 end, case when m2 = 0 then null else m2 end,
    case when m3 = 0 then null else m3 end, case when m4 = 0 then null else m4 end,
    case when m5 = 0 then null else m5 end, case when m6 = 0 then null else m6 end,
    case when m7 = 0 then null else m7 end, case when m8 = 0 then null else m8 end,
    case when m9 = 0 then null else m9 end, case when m10 = 0 then null else m10 end,
    case when m11 = 0 then null else m11 end, case when m12 = 0 then null else m12 end
from 
(
    select id, 
        min(m1) as m1, min(m2) as m2, min(m3) as m3, min(m4) as m4, min(m5) as m5, min(m6) as m6, 
        min(m7) as m7, min(m8) as m8, min(m9) as m9, min(m10) as m10, min(m11) as m11, min(m12) as m12
    from 
    (
        select t.id, extract(month from t.paidDate),
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 1 then 0 else 1 end as m1,
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 2 then 0 else 2 end as m2,
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 3 then 0 else 3 end as m3,
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 4 then 0 else 4 end as m4,
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 5 then 0 else 5 end as m5,
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 6 then 0 else 6 end as m6,
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 7 then 0 else 7 end as m7,
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 8 then 0 else 8 end as m8,
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 9 then 0 else 9 end as m9,
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 10 then 0 else 10 end as m10,
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 11 then 0 else 11 end as m11,
            case when extract(month from t.paidDate) = 12 then 0 else 12 end as m12
        from 
        (
            select 101 as id, '2016-01-01'::date as paidDate union
            select 101 as id, '2016-02-01'::date as paidDate union
            select 101 as id, '2016-04-01'::date as paidDate union
            select 101 as id, '2016-08-01'::date as paidDate union
            select 101 as id, '2016-11-01'::date as paidDate union
            select 102 as id, '2016-01-01'::date as paidDate union
            select 102 as id, '2016-02-01'::date as paidDate union
            select 102 as id, '2016-04-01'::date as paidDate union
            select 102 as id, '2016-08-01'::date as paidDate union
            select 102 as id, '2016-11-01'::date as paidDate
        ) t
    ) t
    group by 
    t.id
) t
```

That's it, hope that it helps a little bit.

Regards